# InvalidTypeIdException from response from swagger generated code

Tags: java, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I am trying to resolve an issue where the json response will not map to the expected response object. This is generated from an api-spec using swagger-code-generator-plugin.

The error is as follows:
HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error:
Could not resolve type id 'loanPart' as a subtype of api.LoanPart: known type ids = [LoanPart, bridgeLoan, revolvingLoanPart] (for POJO property 'loanPart');

Is this somehow a generation issue that I can fix?
The model seems to correspond with the json returned.